# Creating -5V supply from a AC/DC adapter

Tags: negative-voltage

I want to use a [Friwo FOX12-XM](https://docs.rs-online.com/16b0/0900766b816002bd.pdf) [5.9V adapter from RS](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ac-dc-adapters/1618174) with a -5V LDO to create a -5V supply which I draw as follows:

[image]

Would this be fine and is the adapter isolated?

Comment: Should be no issues if you have low enough dropout for 900 mV headroom. What LDO are you using?

Comment: Thats a very good point. I need though hole -5V LDO with such headoom and need to buy from RS or mouser. And couldn't find the proper component(LDO).

Comment: For the adapter I can go for 7.5V or 6V as well.

Comment: What does prevent use of the 5 V model?

Comment: Is there a good reason for not just buying the 5 V version instead?

Comment: If it is an isolated, why use a -5V regulator, as it makes no difference as long as there is 5V over the output in some polarity?

Comment: @Justme I want to filter it since the adapter is probably SMPS type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *is the adapter isolated?*

Because the wall-wart is a medical switch mode power supply, it **will** provide an isolated output as per page 2 of the [data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/16b0/0900766b816002bd.pdf): -

[image]

MOPP stands for [Means of patient protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_safety_testing#Means_of_Patient_Protection_(MOPP)) and "2xMOPP" means it is double insulated against 3000 volts input to output.

Of course you can use a negative voltage regulator to produce 5 volts or, you could buy a 5 volt version of the wall-wart or, use a positive voltage regulator. You can use either polarity regulator to generate 5 volts because the input to the regulator is isolated and, it doesn't matter which line you regulate on. In effect you can regard the raw 5.9 volts output as a battery.

If you do decide to use a regulator make sure it's a low-drop-out type; a 7905 or 7805 won't cut the mustard. Positive regulator: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. " or, you could buy a 5 volt version of the wall-wart or, use a positive voltage regulator." I didnt get this part. Could please you draw it. It sounds easier to implement  and find components. ps: I need to go out now in hurry but reply back as soon as I come back today